# cesium-terrain-builder handle .tif to .terrain not correctly

Tags: cesium

I have a **heightmap.tif** on system **WGS84** file in `C:/Users/ctb/data/`

Tilesets dir: `C:/Users/ctb/data/tilesets/`

Then run docker CLI: `docker run -v /c/Users/ctb/data:/data -t -i homme/cesium-terrain-builder:latest bash`

and run command: `ctb-tile -o /data/tilesets/terrain/uo_wgs84 /data/heightmap.tif`

In cesium project I get this:
[image]

but this scale is different every 5 than what should be.

Then I try in Mercator: `gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3857 heightmap.tif heightmap2.tif` and build again.

For compare **heightmap.tif** open in "MicroDEM":
[image]

Is it possible to do something in this situation?

**EDIT:**

GdalInfo for **heightmap.tif**:

`root@9b66b4a58f72:/# gdalinfo -stats /data/heightmap.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: /data/heightmap.tif
       /data/heightmap.tif.aux.xml
Size is 4096, 3430
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (82.888233019881397,55.458638096454301)
Pixel Size = (0.000011216234429,-0.000006375170268)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  82.8882330,  55.4586381) ( 82d53'17.64"E, 55d27'31.10"N)
Lower Left  (  82.8882330,  55.4367713) ( 82d53'17.64"E, 55d26'12.38"N)
Upper Right (  82.9341747,  55.4586381) ( 82d56' 3.03"E, 55d27'31.10"N)
Lower Right (  82.9341747,  55.4367713) ( 82d56' 3.03"E, 55d26'12.38"N)
Center      (  82.9112039,  55.4477047) ( 82d54'40.33"E, 55d26'51.74"N)
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  Min=56.131 Max=98.161
  Minimum=56.131, Maximum=98.161, Mean=63.756, StdDev=6.603
  NoData Value=-32767
  Overviews: 2048x1715, 1024x858, 512x429, 256x215
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=98.160507202148
    STATISTICS_MEAN=63.756109311469
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=56.131080627441
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=6.6032626523927`

P.S. I am sorry for my knowledge of the English language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved a problem setting noData = 0 or minimum height.